# Partitioning for two separate SSDs

Tags: installation, partitioning, ssd

I'm installing Ubuntu on my laptop with two SSD drives:

- 24 GB Sandisk SSD i100 with read/write performance of 450/350 MB/s
- 256 GB Samsung 840 Pro with read/write performance of 540/520 MB/s

The layout I've been thinking is:

- `/boot` partition
- swap partition
- partition for the rest

As you see, the Samsung should be far more performant. So, does putting any of these on the Sandisk make sense? Is there something that would? Or should I just leave it empty?

Comment: I have a Zenbook with a 24GB SSD and a 500GB HDD I tried putting it onto the SSD but did not win. Would I get much benefit from installing it here as opposed to the HDD? Can it boot from the 24GB Sandisk?

Comment: It sounds just like mine. I just replaced the 500 GB HDD with the Samsung SSD. According to [the article on Ultrabook News](http://ultrabooknews.com/2012/06/28/mod-your-asus-ux32vd-from-hybrid-to-ssd-for-free/) it should be possible to install the OS on the SSD drive. Although the performance of the 24 GB SSD is not that great so the benefit might be debatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about using Samsung SSD space put everything in there as it's the best choice, although putting /boot partition on Sandisk SSD can save you some space in the Samsung SSD and it won't affect too much your system, the only thing that would change is a boot time increased for about 5 or 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It has become common practice to put / on a small SSD (32 or 64Gb) and /home on an much larger HDD, SAS or SSHD to speed things up and keep it all low cost and take advantage of cheep access to very large drives (2, 4 or event 8Tb HDD or SSHD). You can access both drives at the same time and read and write will also increase marginally.
Putting / on a small SSD and /home on a larger SSD is even better, access time being that small, no noticeable difference there, but on read and write, certainly so... Mind you, you won't see any noticeable difference if both are M.2... Than comes the question of what to do with swap??? 1. If you have over 8Gb of RAM, I doubt that you'll ever need one. Swap is faster on SSD, but never as fast as RAM; and keep in mind that swap on an SSD shortens its life, so go for more RAM instead. But, should you need one, put it on the small SSD if it is is at least 64Gb or otherwise on the larger one if it is only 32Gb. To lengthen the life of the 64Gb SSD, get an SLC instead of an MLC SSD... **Don't forget that you should always keep at least 10% of your SSD free at all times**